# Context Deadline exceeded while running kubectl interfaceservices command

Tags: nodes, rpc, kubectl, network-interface

I installed network edge setup for OpenNESS 20.06. `Kubernetes get nodes` command is showing status as "Ready" for worker and master nodes. I am able to login to worker nodes from master node But when I am running  `kubectl interfaceservice get  node02` command from master node where node02 is the hostname of one of my worker node then I am getting this error

```
Error when executing command: [get] err: rpc error: code = DeadlineExceeded desc = context deadline exceeded
```

There may be the situation that time limit is getting exceeded for this command when master node is trying to communicate with worker node. What can be the possible issue and how to resolve that?